# Loading SKShapeNode with custom fillShader causes program to hang

Tags: ios, swift, macos, sprite-kit

I am trying to load a SKShapeNode with a custom fillShader that starts animating when I click my mouse. When I do so, the program starts to hang for around a second or so. Why is this? Is there something wrong with this code?

Where my shader is made:

```
func shaderSprite(position: CGPoint) -> SKShapeNode {
        let sprite = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000))
        sprite.fillColor = .red
        sprite.strokeColor = .clear
        sprite.position = position
        sprite.zPosition = -1
        sprite.fillShader = SKShader(fileNamed: "inkBlobShader.fsh")
        sprite.position = position
        return sprite
}
```

Adding the node:

```
func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    //add the sprite to the scene. (THIS IS WHERE THINGS START LAGGING)
    self.addChild(self.shaderSprite(position: pos))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lag is likely because of `sprite.fillShader = SKShader(fileNamed: "inkBlobShader.fsh")` causing the shader to be compiled.  Try compiling the shader when the scene loads and holding onto a reference instead of waiting until the user interacts with the scene to load and compile the shader.